# Injecting "ng-click" in HTML with ngSanitize

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on localization with Angular and I'm stuck with one last thing here.

I have this json blob

```
  {
    "key": "_need_to_login_",
    "value": "You need to <a ng-click=\"login()\">log in</a> to add an event.",
    "description": "Banner alert info tell user to login before they can add an event"
  }
```

So with this [Angular i18n](https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-localizationservice) module I will be able to do this

```
{{ "_need_to_login_" | i18n }}
```

The problem is that it contains some markup in there and it will simple escape it and will display this on the page

```
You need to <a ng-click="login()">log in</a> to add an event.
```

But with [ngSanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/%24sanitize) I'm able to unescape that markup and display it correctly as:

---

You need to [log in](http://example.com) to add an event.

---

But I don't have that `ng-click` inserted as well.

Try copy that and test it here : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

My question is that how can I insert `ng-click` from the injected code as well as unescape the string?

Comment: Think you need to look at $compile though it's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, could you maybe simplify or show a simpler example in plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: @shaunhusain this is a simple example of what I'm trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/942RA/80/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-bind-html should do what you want. Let me know how it works out, we are planning to add translation support soon to our app.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Edit2: nevermind about the jsfiddle edit. It didnt work.

Comment: Hi @alexc - It doesn't work the way I expected it to be. Please see example here http://jsfiddle.net/942RA/80/

Comment: So basically if my string contain "ng-click" in the variable and trying to add that to the element only `ng-click` is not being added.

Comment: `data-ng-click` is what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: @Ali, did it work? I am having trouble to reproduce it on jsfiddle

Comment: It's working now @alexc by taking it off from the markup and put `data-ng-click` in the element itself :)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I'm running into the same issue at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737927/angular-ng-bind-html-filters-out-ng-click", but using data-ng-click didn't work for me.