# Functions in dynamic AngularJS html

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a forum where the replies are written with AngularJS (ng-repeat).
A reply can contain links, and on all links, I have added a ng-click. This ng-click is not fired.

I guess it is because by the time the link is written to the dom, AngularJS is done hooking up functions. Are there any workarounds?

Here is an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Jg0jVOpPL1LcVPHe5YQz?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.htmlBody = '<a href="http://www.google.com" ng-click="testmethod()" target="_blank">This does not work</a>';

    $scope.toTrustedHtml = function(htmlCode) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    };

    $scope.testmethod = function()
    {
       alert('yes');
    }
});


<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <a href="http://www.google.com" ng-click="testmethod()" target="_blank">This works</a>
   <br /><br />
   <p ng-bind-html="toTrustedHtml(htmlBody)"></p>
</body>
```

Thanks
Rasmus

Comment: And your code is? How have you added an ng-click?

Comment: You need to post some code if you want help, otherwise you'll just get downvotes... ng-click in a repeat should be fine, so you are not using Angular correctly

Comment: have a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737927/angular-ng-bind-html-filters-out-ng-click

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo for your case: [jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6469/](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/6469/).

The idea is that you need to use `$compile` to let angular know you are adding dynamic functions.

Comment: I don't add elements with JavaScript. It is a complete bodytext with links in it. Can I do it a similar way?

Comment: As I said, the jsfiddle just gave you an idea what to do, not exactly your case. I think you can still use $compile. Give a shot and let us know.

Comment: I used the directive that Lee Willis suggested, but this seems to work too. Thanks.

Comment: I took a look at that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737927/angular-ng-bind-html-filters-out-ng-click, it needs to change html and js and it is overly complicated.

Comment: All I had to do was to include the directive in my project and use  <p compile="htmlBody"></p> instead of <p ng-bind-html="toTrustedHtml(htmlBody)"></p>

Comment: So you don't need to add compile directive in js file?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I added/included the compile directive to my project.