# How to make ng-click from injected html to work?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angularjs-ng-click

I'm using datatables along with angular and I have this piece of code:

```
   render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
         var buttonHtml = '<div style="text-align: center;">' +
                          '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-ng-click="loadModal(' + meta.row + ')">' +
                          '<i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp;View' +
                          '</button>' +
                          '</div>';

         return buttonHtml;
    }
```

The above it's a handler from datatables to dynamically format a column based on data.

The problem is that the ng-click handler (loadModal) is never called and I guess because the html is never compiled. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: is meta.row integer or string ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: [Angular: ng-bind-html filters out ng-click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737927/angular-ng-bind-html-filters-out-ng-click) it includes an example of a compile directive.