# AngularJS ng-click is not working from filter

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-bind-html

I am trying to add a a-tag with a filter to an html-content. I'm binding the html-content with ng-bind-html and the a-tag contains ng-click. But my problem is, ng-click is not working.

I am doing this in the html file

```
<div ng-bind-html="text | addLink"></div>
```

my filter looks like this

```
app.filter('addLink', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(text) {
    text += '';
    text += '<a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="readMore()">readMore</a>'
    text = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    return text;
  }
}]);
```

and this is my controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {

  var text = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>' +
            '<p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>'

  $scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  $scope.readMoreIsCalled = 'read more was not called yet';

  $scope.readMore = function() {
    console.log("READ MORE");
    $scope.readMoreIsCalled = 'Read more method was called';
  }

}]);
```

[I created a Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGeB6jhdyAgG7o5mHWB5?p=preview)

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a common problem.  This happens when your bind html but you dont compile it ( it doesn't go through and read all the directives in your html) .   I've seen people use a custom `compile` directive to fix this.  There are other answers out there just google around.  https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/312mbg/ngclick_on_element_inserted_using_ngbindhtml_not/

Comment: Instead of using a filter. I would recommend using a directive with a $compile . Check this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737927/angular-ng-bind-html-filters-out-ng-click

Comment: @Nix and aayush shrestha Thank you very much. I tried your solutions and it's working now.

Comment: @stefOCDP I'd second the use of a directive in this situation, here's an example of how you can use a directive in your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MyXTiuBAI9AXDMlN3Dr9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I could find the solution with the help from the comments. I just had to create a new directive, to compile the inserted html content.
Here is my code

index.html

```
<div compile="text | addLink"></div>
```

filter

```
app.filter('addLink', [function() {
  return function(text) {
    text += '';
    text += '<a class="btn btn-link" ng-click="readMore()">readMore</a>'
    return text;
  }
}]);
```

the new directive

```
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function(scope) {
        // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
        return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
      },
      function(value) {
        // when the 'compile' expression changes
        // assign it into the current DOM
        element.html(value);

        // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
        // scope.
        // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
        // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
  );
};
}]);
```

the controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var text = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>' +
            '<p>Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</p>'

  $scope.text = text;
  $scope.readMoreIsCalled = 'read more was not called yet';

  $scope.readMore = function() {
    console.log("READ MORE");
    $scope.readMoreIsCalled = 'Read more method was called';
  }

}]);
```

[This is the working Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGeB6jhdyAgG7o5mHWB5?p=preview)

But notice, now it's not necessary anymore to use

```
$scp.trustAsHtml()
```