# Ionic Framework, html & Angular Content from scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Scopevariable which contains the html-Code of a button with a *ng-click* Attribute and want to assemble the the Page dynamically.

```
$scope.myHtml = "<button class="someclass" ng-click="clickme()">Button</button>
```

and i am currently using the html like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myHTML"></div>
```

The Button displays pretty fine but the *ng-click* got removed, so how can i keep the angular expressions from the variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an error in : $scope.myHtml = "<button class="someclass" ng-click="clickme()">Button</button>, it will give js error in console, don't have you checked?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737927/angular-ng-bind-html-filters-out-ng-click

Comment: This works, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$scope.myHtml = '<button class="someclass" ng-click="clickme()">Button</button>';
```

Comment: I did it like this, just took the wrong quotes in the Question.. sorry, But the Comment from @astrocrack seems to work :)